# Scheme forEach function

Tags: scheme

The question asks to write a forEach function that satisfies the following interaction. It says the function should create closure around the list and behavior.

```
(define iterator (forEach (list 1 2 3 4 5)))
(iterator (lambda (x)(* x x))) → (1 4 9 16 25)
(iterator (lambda (x)(* x 10))) → (10 20 30 40 50)
```

I can't seem to figure it out. Here's how I've started but I could be way off:

```
(define (map procedure items)
    (if (null? items)
        '()
        (cons (procedure (car items))
              (map procedure (cdr items)))))

(define (forEach l) (lambda (x)
         (cond ((not (null? l))
         (x (car l))
         (forEach (map x (cdr l)))))))

(define iterator (forEach (list 1 2 3 4 5)))
(iterator (lambda (x)(* x x)))
(iterator (lambda (x)(* x 10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `forEach` returns a function that takes a function to `map` over the list that is in the closure.

How you map can be by roll your own recursion or with `map` itself, but certainly not both. Also calling `forEach` from `forEach` result will make it lazy evaluation rather than mapping.

Note that `forEach` is following CamelCase and not lisp-case which is a more common naming convention in lisp languages. The correct name would be `for-each`. Unfortunately there is a higher order function by that name which does the same as `map` but does not accumulate the result.

Here is what you are trying as a recursive solution that does not use `map`:

```
(define (iterate lst)
  (lambda (fn)
    (define (aux lst)
      (if (null? lst)
          '()
          (cons (fn (car lst))
                (aux (cdr lst)))))
    (aux lst)))

(define iterator (iterate '(1 2 3)))
(iterator -) ; ==> (-1 -2 -3)
```

`aux` does pretty much what `map` does except it has `fn` from closure so we can take that out and use your version by passing `fn`:

```
(define (iterate lst)
  (lambda (fn)
    (map fn lst)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` takes a list and returns a function.
This returned function should take another function and apply that to each element of the list.
"Apply a function to each element of a list" is what `map` does:

```
(iterator (lambda (x)(* x x))) → (map (lambda (x)(* x x)) (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(iterator (lambda (x)(* x 10))) → (map (lambda (x)(* x 10)) (list 1 2 3 4 5))
```

So, all you need is

```
(define (forEach ls)
    (lambda (fn) (map fn ls)))
```